# CSS HTML how to ignore some css for non ie7 or ie8

Tags: html, css

So I have the following CSS for getting a background image to size to 100% of my div.

```
#solutionsNav div.leadgen {
background:url(/images/leadGen_bg2.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;  
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/leadGen_bg2.png', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/leadGen_bg2.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
behavior: url(/scripts/PIE.htc);
padding: 10px;
color: #FFF;
cursor: pointer;
```

}

This seems to work now in all browsers but the only problem is that in IE7 and IE8 I can see the outline of the background:url(/images/leadGen_bg2.png) when the image is stretched to fit the div. And I have tested that if I take out background:url(/images/leadGen_bg2.png) in the above it works fine still in IE7 and IE8 but can no longer see it in firefox.

How could I get around this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a conditional comment to load a stylesheet exclusively for IE8 and below, and use it to load all your hax.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie-hax.css" /><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Ah yes this looks what  should be doing I just don't have control over what stylesheets gets implemented. Is there anyway in the CSS File to implement what browsers should do what...IE in IE7 I can do * is there anything like that for IE8 ?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Kolink's answer:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
#solutionsNav div.leadgen { background: none; }
<![endif]-->
```

Make sure this rule comes after your rule you defined in your answer, so that it takes precedence.  Using a separate style sheet for your IE hacks is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I use [conditional classes](http://lostmonocle.com/post/108304549/css-tip-conditional-classes) to get around this issue. For example, if you replace your opening `<body>` tag with this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><body class="oldie ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><body class="oldie ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><body class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><body class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><body><!--<![endif]-->
```

...you get a series of classes targetted specifically at Internet Explorer. You can target IE specifically in your CSS, like so:

```
/* Good browsers */
#solutionsNav div.leadgen {
    background:url(/images/leadGen_bg2.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;  
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* IE-specific code */
.oldie #solutionsNav div.leadgen,
.ie8 #solutionsNav div.leadgen {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/leadGen_bg2.png', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/leadGen_bg2.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
    behavior: url(/scripts/PIE.htc);
}
```